# Give tick sign after selecting items of menubar in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have various items in menu bar where I am  trying to give sign of tick after selecting items in menu bar as shown in Image below.

[image]

Please give me some idea.

Comment: Hey this is pyqt not .cpp or .h so why are you bloody marking duplicate ???????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: the docs of PyQt5 point to the docs of Qt5, so that most Qt5 solutions are PyQt5 solutions. 
avoid using "?" many times, it is unnecessary :)

Answer (score 1):

[`QAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) has a method [`setCheckable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#checkable-prop) to enable the behaviour you want. The method [`setChecked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#checked-prop) can be used to toggle the check state.

<s>You can set the [`QIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html) of a [`QAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) when adding it to a [`QMenu`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html) using [`addAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-1). You can then change the `QIcon` using the [`setIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#icon-prop) method of the `QAction`.</s>

<s>Note that this is not exactly the same as what the Windows menu does in the screenshot. But it it a usable way to achieve the same result.</s>

Comment: [QAction.setCheckable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#checkable-prop).

Comment: @ekhumoro Why did I miss this so far? Thanks!